# Installing Python SpeechRecognition package

Tags: python, installation, speech-recognition

Can someone please advise me how to download and install speech_recognition?

I am currently using Python 2.7.12 on Windows 10.

Should I use the command prompt? If yes, can you please show me exactly what I should write in the commands.

I wrote `pip install SpeechRecognition` in the command prompt. But am getting this error:

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

Comment: The Python package's name is actually [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/). So, as its webpage says, do `pip install SpeechRecognition`

Comment: I did that. I first went to my python directory and wrote "pip install SpeechRecognition", but am getting that.." 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."....what should I do?

Comment: `pip` should be in the same directory as `python`, try that. What OS, version, and Python installation are you using? Try a Python installation like Anaconda which comes with many scientific packages preinstalled ("batteries-included"), although that doesn't include `SpeechRecognition`.

Comment: If for some reason your `pip` got broken (and this isn't just a path issue), it is often faster to uninstall and reinstall python.

Comment: Search for the error "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" and you will find, quite literally, tens of thousands of solutions on the web. It is one of the most common Windows console error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this

```
c:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install SpeechRecognition
```

now if that doesn't work its probably that your pip is broken you'll need to uninstall python and install it again.

You can also run this from cmd: (for those getting an error with the above dir..)

```
 python -m pip install SpeechRecognition
```

It hope it will work